# Restoring my iPhone - will I get my content back?

Tags: iphone

I have to restore as new so I can turn off the restrictions code and then be able to delete apps. Will I be able to get my contacts, music back etc?

Comment: Note that you typically need the restrictions passcode to do a standard wipe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If your iPhone was ever connected to iTunes, or synched with iCloud, it was backed up.

To get your music back, it needs to be on iTunes. Same story for all of your apps.

Your contacts, messages and notes are all backed up in iTunes or iCloud.

When you've restored your iPhone, make sure that you choose the option to restore from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

If you backed it up, yes. (I believe iTunes backs iOS devices by default)